# Template partial specialization for multiple types overriding member function

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

I have class member functions defined as follows, providing a specification for one of them and letting the user provide their own specification for others:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
    // specialization provided for integral types
    template <typename Enable = T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<Enable>::value, size_t>::type
        bar(const T& value);

    // provide your own specialization for other types
    template <typename Enable = T>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<Enable>::value, size_t>::type
        bar(const T& value);
};

template <typename T>
template <typename Enable>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<Enable>::value, size_t>::type
    Foo<T>::bar(const T& value) {
    ...
}
```

Now, I'd like to provide a specialization for the function that will work for integral pair types. I have a template metafunction checking for integral pairs defined as follows:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_integral_pair : std::false_type {}; 

template <typename T1, typename T2> 
struct is_integral_pair<std::pair<T1, T2>> {
    static const bool value =
        std::is_integral<T1>::value && std::is_integral<T2>::value;
};
```

Is it possible for me to provide my own specialization such that it works for all integer pairs, perhaps using the template metafunction I defined above?

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit of a contrived example and somewhat difficult to make sense of as-is. However, with a basic change its quite easy to add what you require. First its important to note that what you're defining above are not partial specialisations of `bar` (that would be impossible as you cannot partially specialize a function) but rather overloads. Next, you have a contrived system whereby you have an `Enable` parameter that has nothing to do with the function parameter - is this really your intention? If you made the change that the template parameter of the function is the same type as its variable parameter, the problem becomes straightforward - you add another overload for integral pairs, again using SFINAE to help you. Here is an example way of achieving what you need:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:

    // specialization provided for integral types
    template <typename Enable>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<Enable>::value, size_t>::type
        bar(const Enable& value);

    // provide your own specialization for other types
    template <typename Enable>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<Enable>::value, size_t>::type
        bar(const Enable& value);

    // provide your own specialization for integral pairs 
    template <typename U, typename V>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<U>::value && std::is_integral<V>::value, size_t>::type
        bar(const std::pair<U,V>& value);

};

template <typename T>
template <typename Enable>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<Enable>::value, size_t>::type
    Foo<T>::bar(const Enable& value) 
{
    std::cout << "Integral" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
template <typename Enable>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<Enable>::value, size_t>::type
    Foo<T>::bar(const Enable& value) 
{
    std::cout << "Non-Integral" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
template <typename U, typename V>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<U>::value && std::is_integral<V>::value, size_t>::type
    Foo<T>::bar(const std::pair<U,V>& value) 
{
    std::cout << "Integral pair" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    Foo<int> foo;

    foo.bar(1);              //output "Integral"
    foo.bar(1.0);            //output "Non-Integral"

    foo.bar(std::pair<float, int>(1.0, 1));    //output "Non-integral"
    foo.bar(std::pair<long, int>(1, 1));       //output "Integral pair"
    return 0;
}
```